# Angular Material 2 Remote Autocomplete. How to abort requests?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material Autocomplete to list results based on a search to a remote API (the filtering is done in remote side).

The HTML side:

```html
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Brand" aria-label="Number"
        matInput [formControl]="formControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brands | async" [value]="brand.name">
            {{ brand.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

The TS side:

```ts
this.brands = this.formControl.valueChanges.flatMap(
    q => this._apiService.getVehiclesBrands(q).map(x => x.results)
);
```

At this point, this is working OK. I get the list of brands from remote and I can select a value from the autocomplete list. Now the question is.... how can I abort all the requests every time the input text changes?

There are a lot of examples with remote requests but the idea is not to get all remote results on init. The idea is to get remote results every time the user changes the text input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just changed `flatMap` with `switchMap` and worked like a charm:

```ts
this.brands = this.formControl.valueChanges.switchMap(
    q => this._apiService.getVehiclesBrands(q).map(x => x.results)
);
```

As Benedikt says in a comment, if you abort XHR request while you are typing, the requests are still executed on the server and - at scale - might cause very high loads. It's a good practice to only issue a XHR, for example, 500 milliseconds after the user stopped typing. This will already reduce the amounts of requests. To do this:

```ts
this.brands = this.formControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).switchMap(
    q => this._apiService.getVehiclesBrands(q).map(x => x.results)
);
```

Comment: Please be careful with canceling XHR request while you are typing. The requests are still executed on the server and - at scale - might cause very high loads. A good practice is to only issue a XHR 1 second after the user stopped typing. This will already reduce the amounts of requests.

Comment: Can I ask what the .map(x => x.Results) does exactly? And whats is the results property.